# When making react components es6 syntax why is super initialised with props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I guess I'm not very good at JavaScript.
This is how I've seen react components initialised. The initial set state is done within the constructor.
`export class Counter extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) { 
      super(props);
      this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  }`

why is there always a `super(props)`. Is this required? Is calling super necessary at all? What would happen if super isn't called?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass props in super only if you want to access this.props in constructor of the class.

```
class Base extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        console.log('Base', props);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Base {this.props.name}</div>;
    }

}

class Sub extends Base {

    constructor(props) {
        super({
            name: 'New name prop'
        });
        console.log('Sub', arguments);
    }

}

var sub = <Sub name="Gomic" />

React.render(sub, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Props are by default not assigned in the constructor. They are assinged in the method React.createElement. So `super(props)` should be called only when the superclass's constructor manually assings `props` to `this.props`. When you just extend the `React.Component` calling `super(props)` method will do nothing with `props`.

**Reference:**

https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/should-we-include-the-props-parameter-to-class-constructors-when-declaring-components-using-es6-classes/2781/2

Comment: oh thanks , that makes sense. what happens if `super()` is not called at all?

Comment: super is just equivalent to getInitialState() in ES5